# ASP.NET UrlReferrer

Tags: asp.net, url, httpcontext

I have an ASP.Net application which generates short url for sharing. I want to track the url from where (source) click occured when it hits my asp.net page. I tried using Context.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri but all I get from it is null.

Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: possible duplicate of [Request.UrlReferrer null!?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149130/request-urlreferrer-null)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that the referrer will sometimes be null for things like search engines, or people behind corporate firewalls that remove some HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite as clean, but you could use Request.Headers["Referer"].  Should be the same as using Context.Request, but I've found the behavior to be different.

Comment: Context.Request just converts it to a URI.  The "referer" in the header, according to the spec (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.36 ) could be a relative URI to the Request URI.  Context.Request takes just takes care of that for you, and gives you a URI to work with. That is where the behavior would be different.