# Asp.net request.UrlReferrer is null

Tags: asp.net, referrer

in my web application Request.UrlReferrer is null. how can i set UrlReferrer ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Request.UrlReferrer null!?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149130/request-urlreferrer-null)

Comment: what do you need it for? IMO you better look for alternative way as the referrer is not stable to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set the UrlReferrer. The referrrer is something that the browser sends to the server. This property is how you read what the browser sent as a referrer. For obvious reasons you cannot set what the browser sends you because your server does not control it.

Why do you want to set it anyway?

Comment: actualy i don't want to set UrlReferrer, I want to be sure that UrlReferrer is not null. But in my application(when i logged in) is null.

Comment: You cannot depend on UrlReferrer because the browser may not send it. What is more someone can open the page directly.

Answer (score 0):

you want to make sure UrlReferrer is not null.  if you do not it can  create 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error.

```
if (!(Request.UrlReferrer == null)) {
    'if Request.UrlReferrer is not null do this 
}
else {
    'set Request.UrlReferrer to null
}
```