# How to redirect users based on what page they came from?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have a page (Controller Action that renders a View) that a user could navigate to from 3 different pages.  Basically, a user gets there, does a few selections and clicks on Save button.  At this point, I need to redirect the user to where he came from.

I'm wondering, what's the best practice to do that?

I know, for example, I could look in Request, figure out where he came from, then redirect back to there...  But that doesn't look like the ideal approach to me.

Comment: there's a potential issue with this code as the UrlReferrer value will be populated based on the header values sent from the browser. For more info have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149130/request-urlreferrer-null

Comment: I am trying to do as you said you end up doing - it behaves differently in Chrome and IE and most importantly, incorrect in both cases. In chrome it doesn't go back, redirecting to current view, in IE it is redirecting to non existing path (controller is missing in the path). Not sure how you end up doing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm wondering, what's the best practice to do that?

Pass a `returnUrl` parameter when invoking this action. Store it in a hidden field if necessary. Make sure that the controller action that performs the validation and needs to redirect gets this parameter as action argument somehow and when the time comes `return Redirect(returnUrl);`

Comment: How would I get it in the first place?  Grab it from Request?

Comment: @Dimskiy: Good thinking.  What other source of information is there?

Comment: @Dimskiy, have the controller action take it as action parameter: `public ActionResult(string returnUrl) { ... }` and then ensure that when calling this action the `returnUrl` parameter is passed.

Comment: @S.Lott - nothing really.  It's the same object that is used for the model, it's just populated with different data.  Can't think of anything else really.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - I guess, I'll just grab it from Request inside the Action of the View that's being called from other places.  I don't want to hardcode that param inside calling actions, unless there is a way to grab it programmaticaly.

Comment: I updated my question with the solution that I ended up with.  Not 100% what you suggested, but you got me going in this direction.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

This is what I ended up doing.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   ViewBag.Referrer = Request.UrlReferrer.LocalPath;
   //.....
   return View();
}
```

**View (Razor syntax):**

```
<a href="@ViewBag.Referrer">Back</a>
```