# what does UrlReferrer exactly mean?

Tags: c#, asp.net, request

what does UrlReferrer(`Request.UrlReferrer` & `Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString`) exactly mean?
i wrote these codes :

```
    if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
    {
        User_Info.Add(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString) ? Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString : string.Empty);//6:UrlReferrer
    }
    else
    {
        User_Info.Add(string.Empty);
    }
```

i just know ReturnUrl querystring when a user tries to login to admin area.
so in web.config `<authentication mode="Forms">`
and now we have UrlReferrer server-side code.
i want to gather some information about my users of my web site such as User-Agent , User-Browser , Session-ID , etc...
but i really do n't know what does UrlReferrer exactly do and it is always null.(i think because of wrong usage)
would you please give me a simple example for understanding.

thanks for attention

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Request.UrlReferrer null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149130/request-urlreferrer-null)

Comment: thanks bro, another useful thread. but i need this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

quote:

> When visiting a webpage, the referrer or referring page is the URL of
>   the previous webpage from which a link was followed.

for more information you can go to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

It can be null if you someone opened a browser and just entered your site address (without pressing a link to get there)

Comment: just one (the last page address that was the reference to your link)

Comment: Not entirely correct. The referrer is the url from which the http request was issued. When a page load an image, the request to that image will contain the url of the page as referrer.