# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Redirect to the same page after controller ends

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

From a page I have the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddEntry", "Configure", FormMethod.Get, new { returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl }))
{
    @Html.TextBox("IP")
    @Html.Hidden("TypeId", 1)
    <input type="submit" value="@Resource.ButtonTitleAddComponent" />
}
```

so controller is called correctly:

```
public ActionResult AddEntry(string ip, int TypeId, string returnUrl)
{
    // Do some stuff

    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

My problem is that returnUrl gets null and it does not redirect to the same page that called the controller. Ideas?

Using: ASP.NET MVC 4
       Razor

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use a `Request.QueryString` method to get some values from URL, for sample:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddEntry", "Configure", FormMethod.Get, null))
{
    @Html.TextBox("ip")
    @Html.Hidden("TypeId", 1)
    @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", this.Request.RawUrl)
    <input type="submit" value="@Resource.ButtonTitleAddComponent" />
}
```

And in your controller, receive it as a parameter `string returnUrl`.

Comment: In the controller, parameter returnUrl continues being null with this attempt. What I want is: I have a view that has the code indicate, when I submit this values to the controller, I want that once the controller ends it returns to the same page from where submit was invoked.

Comment: Also, check the html output to see if the View is getting the value from URL with `Request.QueryString`.

Comment: @user1624552 Replace that `QueryString` with `this.Request.RawUrl`. @FelipeOriani the URL to redirect is the current URL from the requesting form.

Comment: As @AndreCalil says, it is this.Request.RawUrl instead of QueryString. It works! :) passing QueryString, the controller receives an empty string. Also,no need to pass null at the end of Html.BeginForm.

Comment: As you answered first and your solution works ok, I have voted you as the accepted answer. Also, as my question was about passing a parameter to return to the caller page, I have choosen your answer as the accepted. Other solutions commented here also work, and maybe they are more cleaner because there is no need to pass an extra parameter.

Answer (score 50):

you can also do this if you need to return to something like details page and return to the same page with a query:

```
return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery);
```

Comment: I am on page 'A', from there I navigate to page 'B'. 
Now I Refresh page 'B'.

In such cases, Request.UrlReferrer return 'B', however I am expecting 'A'.

Any Help??

Comment: This may not work depending on your "Post Redirect Get" strategy.  If you have a validation error on the form, the `UrlReferrer` may end up being the page itself.

Answer (score 17):

You can get the Refer URL from the `Request` in the controller:

```
public ActionResult AddEntry(string ip, int TypeId, string returnUrl)
{

     // Do some stuff
     string url = this.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath;

     return Redirect(url);
}
```

This will redirect you exactly to the calling URL.

Comment: Your solution also works like a charm. no need to pass returnUrl to the controller from the page.

Comment: Also, Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri works. What is the difference between Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri and Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath? Both work.

Comment: You should use it carefully, it may be [null] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149130/request-urlreferrer-null).

Comment: To handle if its null I just picked a default action it should go to if I don't have a referrer, this works a treat.

Comment: Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri  will  concatenate querystrings eg if  the first attempt has  yoururl.com?msg=error and the action is repeated and this time successful in this view the redirect will become yoururl.com?msg=error?msg=success so I recommend  using AbsolutePath

Comment: I had a hard time finding the question, but this answer worked excellently for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 10):

in your controller class use `Request.UrlReferrer`. There's no need to pass the url from the page.

```
   public ActionResult AddEntry(string ip, int TypeId)
    {

         // Do some stuff

         return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: There a error there! UrlReferrer is an Uri, you should pass string to Redirect.

Comment: Right, I was not on the computer to check it, fixed

Comment: There's no need to convert to string. By doing Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddEntry", "Configure", new { returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl }))
{
    @Html.TextBox("IP")
    @Html.Hidden("TypeId", 1)
    <input type="submit" value="@Resource.ButtonTitleAddComponent" />
}
```

Change your code like this

Answer (score 0):

I found that using UrlReferrer works well and allows me to add on extra params if needed.

**Helper method example:**

```
protected RedirectResult RedirectToCurrentUri(String strQueryStringOverride = "")
{
    String strReferrer = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strReferrer))
    {
        strReferrer = "/";
    }

    // Can also override referrer here for instances where page has 
    // refreshed and replaced referrer with current url.

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strQueryStringOverride))
    {
        String strPath = (strReferrer ?? "").Split('?', '#')[0];

        return Redirect(strPath + strQueryStringOverride);
    }

    return Redirect(strReferrer);
}
```

Note that the method allows Query String override.

**This can be used as a helper method in any controller as per below:**

Redirect without changing query string (if any):

```
return RedirectToCurrentUri()
```

Example query string override:

```
return RedirectToCurrentUri("?success=true")
```

Answer (score -2):

1. on Get like `Edit(int? id)`

   ```
   ViewBag.RefUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
   ```
2. on view `@Html.Hidden("RefUrl");`
3. on post `Edit(int id,string RefUrl)`

   ```
   return Redirect(RefUrl);
   ```