# Restrict Web App to IP address or DNS name

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, dns

Here is the situation:

We have an application "A" to which our customer login. After successful logging in, they can see a link to web application "B".

Web application B is an ASP.Net application hosted on IIS 7. What is  the best way using programming to make application B accessible only when users come through the website "A".

Comment: do they both use the same domain?

Comment: Do you have access to both applications?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: application A is not an asp.net app?

Comment: I don't have access to Application A and not sure how it is hosted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty much doing some kind of "3rd party authentication" scheme, not unlike "Google/Facebook, etc." sign-in. SO does same - I "login" to SO via Google Sign in...

So depending on how your "protocols" are defined with `Site A`, which you have stated isn't under your control but since there is some *trust* you seem to require and cede to it, then I would think there is "some" protocol in place.

Barring that, or if you are in search of some protocol between Sites A and B, and depending on just how secure you need things to be, then it may just boil down to implementing similar schemes  - e.g. token, http headers, etc.

Trivial example:

- link from **Site A**:  http://www.GoToSiteB.com/?token=unique_token_you_need_to_verify

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
 Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

It is not entirely trusted, but depending on the level of your user, you could do worse.

See:  [Request.UrlReferrer null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149130/request-urlreferrer-null)