# How to get the previous url in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-rewriting

How to get the previous url in a MasterPage in C# ?

I'm trying to find the page which is redirected from.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your previous page has to pass that information to new one (or you can store such information in session).

Comment: How can I get this ? But I'm searching without using session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you use a query string parameter to achieve this: `current?previousUrl=/some/11`.

This will allow you to access this value from the server-side code using `Context.Request.QueryString["previousUrl"]` in your master page code-behind.

Comment: This doen't work, it gets null, unfortinately (in code behind) (but using some query string parameters can fix my problem, thanks.

Comment: Hello, in fact, I'm testing it by doing a response redirect in code behind.

Comment: @Bengi And this is correct. You might be doing something wrong.

Comment: I didn't try with using url parameters, but I'm sure it will work with url parameters... The thing is; I need to solve this within code-behind (not by using url parameters). But I think this is not possible upon @Tasos K.'s post.

Comment: I'm testing with blank new pages, redirecting from Default1.aspx to Default2.aspx, and testing at Default2's PageLoad event.

Answer (score 17):

You can get information of the previous url with the `UrlReferrer` property. This works in MVC and Web forms.

```
Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri
```

Note that in the first page the property `Request.UrlReferrer` will be null. Also, it will be null if a redirection occurs (e.g. when a user logs into the web page).

This property is based on the **HTTP_REFERER** variable, so you could use this one instead.

```
Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

Since the HTTP_REFERER is a variable sent by the client it might be altered or removed by the request. Also, the variable is not set when the referre url starts with `https`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149130/request-urlreferrer-null) article mentions a few points why the `Request.UrlReferrer` can be null.

Comment: But it gets error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: The error occurs when the first page loads? If yes, add a check `if(Request.UrlReferrer != null) {...}`

Comment: No I checked in second page. (Im trying at an Asp.Net website)

Comment: Does the second page loads after a redirection? Then yes, it also should be null. I updated my answer by adding a few more information regarding that matter

Comment: I have check the new one (HTTP_REFERER) but its still gets null... I'm testing with blank new pages, redirecting from Default1.aspx to Default2.aspx, as you say and testing at Default2's PageLoad event.

Comment: If you are doing a redirect, it **should** be null. It will not be null if the user is in page `default1.aspx` and clicks a links to the page `default2.aspx`

Comment: Yep I see my fault and works now by clicking link. But is it possible redirecting in code behind ? What can I do for that ?

Comment: When redirecting from code behind, you could follow @MatíasFidemraizer answer, there you could easily put a query string when doing the redirection

Comment: Your second example is the one I tried first. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
string urlName = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

As of .NET 6.0 the UrlReferrer object is deprecated from the Request (HttpRequest) object. It is now stored as a part of the Request.Headers dictionary.

The new way to access the UrlReffer object would be:

```
string urlReferrer = Request.Headers["Referer"]!.ToString();
```

Note: this object may be null in certain cases. It would be most safe to first check if the object is null before accessing it.

```
string? urlReferrer = null;
if (Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Referer"))
{
    urlReferrer = Request.Headers["Referer"]!.ToString();
}
```